# Java garbage collection is performed, but GC notification is not received

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, javabeans, jmx

I have followed a few examples from various sources, and have the following snippet:

```
 private void registerForMemUsageChanges() {
    List<GarbageCollectorMXBean> garbageCollectorMXBeans = ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans();
    for (GarbageCollectorMXBean garbageCollectorMXBean : garbageCollectorMXBeans) {
        listenForGarbageCollectionOn(garbageCollectorMXBean); 
    }

}

private void listenForGarbageCollectionOn(GarbageCollectorMXBean garbageCollectorMXBean) {
    NotificationEmitter notificationEmitter = (NotificationEmitter) garbageCollectorMXBean;
    GarbageListener listener = new GarbageListener();
    notificationEmitter.addNotificationListener(listener, null, null);
}

public class GarbageListener implements NotificationListener {

    @Override
    public void handleNotification(Notification notification, Object handback) {
        if (notification.getType().equals(GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.GARBAGE_COLLECTION_NOTIFICATION)) {
            doSomthing();//irrelevant
        }

    }
}
```

I have added a test that does the following (again, based on examples I found) and it seems to work:

```
private void triggerGc() throws InterruptedException {
    Object obj = new Object();
    WeakReference ref = new WeakReference<Object>(obj);
    obj = null;
    while(ref.get() != null) {
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

While running in debug mode I see that the listener is registered to ps marksweep and ps scavenge. **The while loop finished (which I take as a sign that GC was performed)** but no notification is called. Not a GC notification or of any type.

Is the problem that the listener is registered wrong or was GC not really performed? it seems that the weak ref is indeed empty after the while loop.

I am using openjdk 1.8.0_144.

Comment: System.gc is not an order, it's a recommendation. There are no guarantees that the gc will actually be performed.

Comment: @Erik Agree, but as I mention in the post, there is a test that waits for GC to be performed and check it by using a WeakReference to an object that is being cleaned. If this isn't a sufficient indication for GC then what is?

Comment: But is there a reason for the gc to run? What does the heap look like? If there are space enough, why should it run?

Comment: I also tried creating a lot of object, but let's say I didn't. The fact that the ref is empty should mean that it did actually ran GC.

Comment: Look at the gc log.

Comment: It seems, it doesn’t send any notification when only the Young Generation changes. When I create enough objects to affect the Old Generation, I get notifications. Which makes me wonder whether there is any documentation about whether and which notifications are supposed to be sent. Or is finding out that the object implements `NotificationEmitter` at runtime the best we can get?

Answer (score 1):

The problem actually was:

1. As Holger mentioned in a comment, I was only getting notification for GC that affected the old generation, and
2. Debugger did not stop at my breakpoint, though the code was executed, so even though I couldn't tell, doSomething actually did something.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [System.gc()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc()) javadoc says

> Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend
>   effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory
>   they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns
>   from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort
>   to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

Calling garbage collector does not means that garbage will collected immediately on call. But by calling gc you can only suggest JVM to collect garbage but cannot force it.

Comment: See my other comment. In the post I explain that I run this with a test that has while loop until the object is cleaned. The weak reference is indeed empty.